# Hooking up Angular 2 reactive form with Firebase - load and reload form data

Tags: forms, angular, firebase, promise

I have a basic reactive form where inputed values also get displayed in a table at the bottom of the form.

Using the code below I can successfully:

- load the form component, input and submit data to firebase via my dataService component
- access previously submitted data from firebase which gets saved to a local variable `response` and can be referenced on the page using interpolation `{{response}}`

**I want to be able to access and display previously submitted form data from the db on loading the form.**

*However*, if I try the approach of setting my form values to reference the `response` values the form fails.

e.g. something like:

```
this._fb.group({
               title: [this.response.title],
               version: [this.response.version]
        });
```

I figure this is an issue of the form data not becoming available prior to the form being initiated

My dataService is already an argument in the constructor and registered as a provider in the app.module.ts

**What do I need to amend in the code and what concept is key to accessing form data as required from the db?**

Is this a scenario where I need to introduce a Promise or an Observable?

Any help appreciated. Thanks 


**app.component.ts** extract

```
declare var firebase: any;

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    public myForm: FormGroup;
    response: string;

    constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder, private dataService: DataService) { 
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getEntry();

        this.myForm = this._fb.group({        
             title: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
             version: ['', [Validators.required]]
        });
    }

    getEntry() {
        this.dataService.getEntryData('form')
          .subscribe(
            (form) => this.response = JSON.stringify(form)
          ); 
    }

    setEntry() {
         var newEntryName = "/" + this.myForm.value.title + "_v" + this.myForm.value.version + "/";

        this.dataService.setEntryData(newEntryName,this.myForm.value.title, this.myForm.value.version)
          .subscribe(
            (newEntryName:string) => this.response = JSON.stringify(newEntryName)
          );
    }

}
```

**data.sevice.ts** extract

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService { 

constructor(private http: Http) {} 

   getEntryData(entry:string){
       var url =  "https://myurlhere.firebaseio.com/" + entry + ".json";
     return this.http.get(url)
       .map((response:any) => response.json());
   }

   setEntryData(entry:string, title:string, version:number){

     var url =  "https://myurlhere.firebaseio.com/" + entry + ".json";
     const body = JSON.stringify({title: title, version: version});

     return this.http.put(url, body)
       .map((response:any) => response.json());
   }
}
```